# How do I know if a WCF Service is alive in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have done everything in the `Working With WCF` tutorial in the following link: [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/web_services/walkthrough_working_with_WCF/)  and I have successfully created a WCF Service. But how can I know if the service is alive?

Xamarin, Android C#

Comment: You will get exception when trying to access dead service.

Comment: I have trying using `try` and `catch` when accessing the service but no result. I also tried it in the completed of the function but still no result.

Comment: Add method `IsAlive` to your service which returns boolean value true. If service is dead you will never get true.

Comment: I already tried but it didn't work...
In the service:
`public bool isAlive()
        {
            return true;
        }
`

and in the android app I used:

`service.isAliveAsync()` but didn't work. App crashes when using that method.